# What are the properties of an unknown object that guarantee that it has mass?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, mass, atomic-physics, atoms

During JJ thomson experiment and similiar other experiments,they found that cathode rays were deflecting from its direction under magnetic fields and electric field,also the gold leaf attached to co-axial cylinders led to conclusion that the cathode rays are negatively charged,but later,By Putting a paddle wheel or fan in path of cathode,the wheel turned and moved,the fan also moved,This led them to conclusion that they must have mass,but is this the only criteria required for an unknown object to have mass,that they can perform mechanical work?The scientists at that time concluded that they have mass,and then went on to calcultate charge to mass ratio of it,assuming rays has mass?Can't any other particle now known do work as well as have no mass?

Comment: The paddle wheel experiment is not a good example as  Starke after a number of linked experiments concluded that thermal effects were greater than the mechanical impulse imparted by the electrons.

Comment: [A Century-Old Question: Does a Crookes
Paddle Wheel Cathode Ray Tube Demonstrate
that Electrons Carry Momentum?](https://fathomingphysics.nsw.edu.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/TEHumphrey_VCalisa_Phys_Teach_vol_52_iss_3_142_2014.pdf) and the links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, Thomson's experiments demonstrated that cathode rays carry *momentum*. It is indeed a requirement for a particle to do work that it must be able to carry momentum. However, a particle that has no momentum (and can never have momentum) is hardly a particle in any normal sense of the term, so this is rather a circular argument.

Comment: I know that during thomson times,anything that carries momentum should be necessarily particle and have mass,but in today's times,it is not the case right?objects  might not have mass still have momentum?so why should we now,after knowing this,still go on with thomson and assume electrons had/have mass?Have we found something new that  indicated electron has mass or particularly rest mass?

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi The correct conclusion from Thomson's experiments is that cathode rays carry momentum. Do you have a primary source where Thomson says they have mass rather than momentum ? Or are you taking this from a secondary source such as a poorly written textbook ?

Comment: https://web.lemoyne.edu/~giunta/ea/THOMSONann.HTML   ,a text extracted from his original papers and lectures

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi In that lecture Thomson shows that the cathode rays travel in a near vacuum with a speed that is about one third the speed of light (and his method for determining this speed makes no assumption about their mass). Since they are not travelling at the speed of light, he is entitled to conclude that non-zero momentum implies non-zero mass.

Comment: as farcher said in above link in comments of question,Rather than the paddle wheel,without assuming cathode ray to be made of particles,how would one find that it had momentum,what part of rutherford's experiments led to conclusion that they had momentum,without assuming they are particles?

Comment: I would like to discuss this conversation,please enter the room,https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148342/mass-of-electron-and-further-discussion